# JQuery TR Vertical Scroller?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there are JQuery plugins out there for vertical scrolling of lists but I have a table and would like to vertically scroll the

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

if i understand u right...u dont need plugin to do this. just add class to this table or id and then from your css set code below to this id/class:

```
#youTable{
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know - you cannot scroll table

what you do instead is putting the table inside a div and make div scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would want to use a `Fixed Header Table`
This plugin will help you achieve it: http://www.tablefixedheader.com/

There was another plugin that allowed you to fix Header and Columns, but since the plugins section of jquery site has been taken down, it seems to have disappeared from existence!
I have uploaded it to my site and you can download it from there: http://files.bpratik.in/jquery.fixer-1.41.zip

Applying it to a table is as easy as:

```
$('table').fixer({
    fixedrows:1,
    fixedcols:1
});
```